# To get create json of Post for each specialities

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many

I have tables

```
+============+  +=================+  +======================+
|    Post    |  |   Specialities  |  |   Speciality_post    |
+============+  +=================+  +======================+
|    title   |  |       id        |  |       post_id        |
+------------+  +-----------------+  +----------------------+
|    image   |  |   specialities  |  |     speciality_id    |
+------------+  +-----------------+  +----------------------+
|    post    |
+------------+
```

With Many to Many relationship

```
$newsjson = newspost::select('id','title','image','post','created_at')
            ->with([
                'specialities'=> function($query) {
                    $query->select('specialities');
                }
            ])->get();
```

What I am getting

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "title": "Post Title",
    "image": "public/VmbDObltSRiOfvpudgy72kK4xryDRIkYGJj0rsDq.jpeg",
    "post": "This is post",
    "created_at": "2017-07-14 05:59:28",
    "specialities": [
        {
            "specialities": "oncology"
        },
        {
            "specialities": "patholgy"
        },
        {
            "specialities": "cardiology"
        }
    ]
```

what I want is

```
{
    "NEWS" : [
        {
            "id":7,
            "title":"Post Title",
            "image":"public\/VmbDObltSRiOfvpudgy72kK4xryDRIkYGJj0rsDq.jpeg",
            "post":"This is post",
            "created_at":"2017-07-14 05:59:28",
            "specialities:oncology"
        }, 
        {
            "title":"Post Title",
            "image":"public\/VmbDObltSRiOfvpudgy72kK4xryDRIkYGJj0rsDq.jpeg",
            "post":"This is post",
            "created_at":"2017-07-14 05:59:28",
            "specialities:pathology"
        },
        {
            "title":"Post Title",
            "image":"public\/VmbDObltSRiOfvpudgy72kK4xryDRIkYGJj0rsDq.jpeg",
            "post":"This is post",
            "created_at":"2017-07-14 05:59:28",
            "specialities:cardiology"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: since you already defined it as a "many to many" you will not get a single specialitiy. It will always be an array unless you transform it to someting else. Since the data is actually correct - where is the exact problem? Why do you need it in this format?

Comment: Can you include the code you're using to get the results in your question as well

Comment: Here this the query I wrote I want to add more but, this site is not allowing me to add more code.